# How to handle the %s format specifier

Tags: ios, swift

Objective-C code:

```
NSString *str = @"hi";
NSString *strDigit = @"1934"; (or @"193" may be a 3 digit or 4 digit value)

[dayText appendFormat:@"%@%4s,str,[strDigit UTF8String]];
```

The Objective-C code handles the output string with current alignment when it appears with 3 or 4 digits as output. It is correctly aligning to left and doesn't matter how much digits it is. Any one know how to handle this in Swift?

In Swift I tried with below code and the string is not adjusting the alignment according to the number of digits.

```
textForTrip += "\(str) \(String(format:"%4s", (strDigit.utf8))"
```

Comment: can you please add the output in your question

Answer (score 2):

The `%s` format expects a pointer to a (NULL-terminated) C string
as argument, that can be obtained with the `withCString` method.
This would produce the same output as your Objective-C code:

```
let str = "Hi"
let strDigit = "193"

let text = strDigit.withCString {
    String(format: "%@%4s", str, $0)
}
print(text)
```

It becomes easier if you store the number as integer instead of a 
string:

```
let str = "Hi"
let number = 934

let text =  String(format: "%@%4d", str, number)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below approach, that might help you

```
let strDigit = "\("1934".utf8)" //(or @"193" may be a 3 digit or 4 digit value)
var dayText = "Hello, good morning."
dayText += "\(strDigit.prefix(3))"
```